# Spring Sleuth - Correlation Id not logging

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

Current flow:
*SchedulerA -> ServiceA -> FeignOfB (Other ServiceB) -> ControllerB*

**log.xml**

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -
            %msg
            ${appName:-}, %X{Correlation-Id:-}, %X{traceId:-}, %X{spanId:-}%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
   sleuth:
     baggage:
       correlation-enabled: true
       correlation-fields:
         - Correlation-Id
       remote-fields:
         - Correlation-Id
```

**Scheduler Code:**

```
public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {
    String cId = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
    BaggageField bField = BaggageField.getByName("Correlation-Id");
    if (bField != null) {
        bField.updateValue(tracer.currentSpan().context(), cId);
    }
    //MDC.put("Correlation-Id", cId);
    log.info("scheduleFixedDelayTask, {}", new Date());
    List<Foo> foos = this.feignService.getData("foo");
    log.info("scheduleFixedDelayTask - completed", new Date());
}
```

Generating **UUID** and setting **BaggageField** value. **Correlation-Id** value prints in **ServiceB** controller but in scheduler log of serviceA from where request originate, it does not print **Correlation-Id**. It prints spanId and traceId in both of the services(self generated).

If I manually set value using **MDC**(the commented line) then it prints.
Is this a right way to manually set the value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure Brave to perform flush on update - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/project-features.html#features-baggage

```
@Bean
ScopeDecorator mdcScopeDecorator() {
    return MDCScopeDecorator.newBuilder()
            .clear()
            .add(SingleCorrelationField.newBuilder(BaggageField.create("Correlation-Id"))
                    .flushOnUpdate()
                    .build())
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, it's working. Is there any instrumentation available for `@JmsListener`? I want some kind of interceptor before message receive to listener and want to check if required Correlation-Id and other things available in header or not.